# Memory or other concerns with multiple div hidden by z-index

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

What should be my concerns about designing a web site with multiple divs stacked upon each other and revealed on demand.

- Projected number of divs = 15

  Content type = text

  Content size of each div = ranging from 5,000 characters up to 100 KB

  Target browsers = Chrome; IE => 8; Firefox, Safari

This is a document retrieval site via AJAX.  The use of the multiple divs stacked in a "deck" would allow me to store past retrievals on the client side and curb the number of exchanges with the server.

Will I run into problems with this design?  What would be some best practices?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance of your question I would say that you should not have any memory issues to worry about, but if you are just wanting to use the div's for storing past retrievals, you could use an array and just update one div instead of keeping several divs on the page.

Especially if your keeping it to a minimum...if you start getting into the hundreds you might see some performance issues if you are toggling the view state of the divs.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I had not considered passing the data into an array and replacing the text of a single div with the content of the array.  This may be a simpler process.  Thank you.